# how to iterate array values and update multiple records in C#

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-firestore, webapi

I want to update multiple records based on the array value. "userid" and "orderid" are array values with comma separated. I want to loop through the array value and update the records of firestore. userid and order id will be having same index. as many numbers of users those many numbers of orderid will be ther.

sample webapi

```
https://localhost:44308/AssignTruck/djK2BjrTTnuLSqD8LbeZ,djK2BjrTTnuLSqD8LbeZ/PdTXq6Rk0WfJK9FQV8vt,TmHhOapTNaZco4PcCF8j/S-1

userid - djK2BjrTTnuLSqD8LbeZ,djK2BjrTTnuLSqD8LbeZ
docid -  PdTXq6Rk0WfJK9FQV8vt,TmHhOapTNaZco4PcCF8j
```

code

```
[HttpGet("/AssignTruck/{userid}/{orderid}/{shipid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AssignTruck(string userid, string orderid, string shipid)
        {
            {
                FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("trucks");
                DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users/" + userid + "/orders").Document(orderid);
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
                Truck truck = null;
                if (snapshot.Exists)
                {
                    truck = snapshot.ConvertTo<Truck>();
                    truck.Docid = snapshot.Id;
                    truck.shipId = shipid;
                }
                else
                {
                }
                await docRef.SetAsync(truck);
                return RedirectToAction("tables");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming that the userids and orderids corresponds to the same index, your code should be as follows:

```
    [HttpGet("/AssignTruck/{userid}/{orderid}/{shipid}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AssignTruck(string userid, string orderid, string shipid)
    {
        string[] uIds= userid.Split(',');
        string[] oIds= orderid.Split(',');

        for(int i=0; i<uIds.Length(); i++) {              
            FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("trucks");
            DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users/" + uIds[i] + "/orders").Document(oIds[i]);
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
            Truck truck = null;
            if (snapshot.Exists)
            {
                truck = snapshot.ConvertTo<Truck>();
                truck.Docid = snapshot.Id;
                truck.shipId = shipid;
            }

            await docRef.SetAsync(truck);
            
        }
        return RedirectToAction("tables");
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (`.length()` is not valid), and if it did, the `return` inside the `for` makes the `for` loop pointless

Comment: thanks for ur code @filissen. im trying this code.

Comment: thanks @filessen ur code is working fine. changes req is  await docRef.SetAsync(truck); should be out of loop and .length()  will be Length